# Get a variable value from a method to another?

Tags: c#

In this situation, I am trying to get the value of "FileSizeType", an integer variable, into the method that's under it "NomCategorie"and convert it to a string(that's what the comment says).

```
static int ChoisirCategory()
        {
            int FileSizeType;
            Console.Write("What type do you want: ");
            FileSizeType = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            return FileSizeType;
        }

static string NomCategorie(int c)
        {
            //get FileSizeType into c
            string FileType;
            if (c == 1)
            {
                return FileType = "Small";
            }
            else if (c == 2)
            {
                return FileType = "Medium";
            }
            else if (c == 3)
            {
                return FileType = "Large";
            }
            else if (c == 4)
            {
                return FileType = "Huge";
            }
            else
            {
                return FileType="Non-valid choice";
        }
```

Comment: You call the method and pass it as a parameter, similar to how you're passing the string that the user entered to the `Convert.ToInt32` method. You could do `string categoryName = NomCategory(ChoisirCategory());` from your `Main` method.

Comment: Well, calling the method with the parameter _seems_ like the obvious choice: `var requestedType = NomCategorie(FileSizeType)`?  Also, `NomCategorie` doesn't need to assign `FileType` just to return the value, it might as well just be (for example) `return "Small";` etc. But, you have set `ChoisirCategory` to return an `int`, so you are going to have to convert the string returned by `NomCategorie`  to an `int` or return a string - or use a `FileType` enum instead?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using enum class

```
public enum Test
{
    Small = 1,
    Medium = 2,
    Large = 3,
    Huge = 4
}
```

then you can simply convert the number by using

```
int integer = 1;
if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Test), integer) 
{
  Console.WriteLine((Test)integer). 
}
else 
{
  Console.WriteLine("Bad Integer");
}

output:
Small
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your existing code, you are already returning the value of `FileSizeType` from the `ChoisirCategory`, so you can capture it in a variable and then pass that to the `NomCategorie` method to get the category name, for example:

```
int categoryId = ChoisirCategory();
string categoryName = NomCategorie(categoryId);
```

Note that there are many other improvements that can be made (for example, what happens if the user types in "two" instead of "2"?), but I think those suggestions may be out of scope based on the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how your code could be simplified if you combine both suggestions above. I've also added an if clause to verify that the value is not higher than those available.

```
static enum AvailableSizes
{
        Small = 1,
        Medium = 2,
        Large = 3,
        Huge = 4
}

static int ChoisirCategory()
{
    int FileSizeType;

GetInput:
    Console.Write("What type do you want: ");
    FileSizeType = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    // Ensure the value is not higher than expected
    // (you could also check that it is not below the minimum value)
    if (FileSizeType > Enum.GetValues(typeof(AvailableSizes)).Cast<int>().Max());
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Value too high.");
        goto GetInput;
    }

    return FileSizeType;
}


static string NomCategorie(int c)
{
    if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(AvailableSizes), c) 
    {
        return (AvailableSizes)c; 
    }
    else 
    {
        return "Invalid category";
    }
}
```

Then somewhere in your code you would call these using this statement

```
string categoryStr = NomCategorie(ChoisirCategory());
Console.WriteLinte(categoryStr);  // or do whatever you want with the returned value
```

With this code, if the input is higher than 4, it will output "Value too high." and ask the question again until the value is no higher than 4.

If the user types 0 or a negative value, then it will output "Invalid category".

This might help you decide where you want to handle input errors: right after user input or during the parsing of the number to a string.